# Python: Append to dictionary in for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm getting unexpected results when trying to populate a dict with output from the Linux fio command.

```
with open('normal_output.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        d = {}

        if ':' not in line:
            continue
        print("LINE: ", line)
        key, value = line.strip().split(':', 1)
        d[key] = value
```

I expect a dictionary full of KVPs like:

```
('KEY: ', 'READ')
('VALUE: ', ' io=131220KB, aggrb=13890KB/s, minb=13890KB/s, maxb=13890KB/s, mint=9447msec, maxt=9447msec')
('KEY: ', 'WRITE')
('VALUE: ', ' io=130924KB, aggrb=13858KB/s, minb=13858KB/s, maxb=13858KB/s, mint=9447msec, maxt=9447msec')
('KEY: ', 'Disk stats (read/write)')
('VALUE: ', '')
('KEY: ', 'sda')
('VALUE: ', ' ios=32642/32600, merge=0/12, ticks=7472/936, in_queue=8392, util=88.18%')
{'sda': ' ios=32642/32600, merge=0/12, ticks=7472/936, in_queue=8392, util=88.18%'}
```

But instead, I'm just getting the very last KVP:

```
{'sda': ' ios=32642/32600, merge=0/12, ticks=7472/936, in_queue=8392, util=88.18%'}
```

I tried d[key].append(value) but that gives me: KeyError: 'fio_test'

Comment: A brief word of warning: [it's attractive but **dangerous** to scrape fio's summary output](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm1GJMp0QN4#t=17m48s). Please consider machine parsing [fio's JSON output](http://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#json-output) instead because it's designed for that purpose and newer versions of fio are less likely to break old scripts that are using it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your loop you're creating a new empty dictionary `d`. Move it outside the `for` loop.

From

```
with open('normal_output.txt', 'rb') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        d = {}
        # do work
```

to

```
with open('normal_output.txt', 'rb') as f:
    d = {}
    for line in f.readlines():
        # do work
```

You can even move the dictionary creation outside the context manager (`with` statement) to keep the logic better organized, but that's more of a matter of taste and style.

Answer (score 3):

You are instantiating the dictionary in the for loop, so every time it loops you are overwriting your dictionary. Bring d={} outside the for loop